# How change build target (2.2 to 2.3.3)? Or recover after trying

Tags: android, eclipse, build, target

I need to change my projects's build target from 2.2 to 2.3.3 in order to use Google API with map support. I changed the manifest's min- and target SdkVersion to 10. And the project's properties|android to 2.3.3. And under my project folder in Eclipse there is then the Android 2.3.3 directory to indicate that the stuff worked out that far.

But when I try to run my application I get the non-informative Eclipse "Problem Occurred" dialog: *An internal error occurred during: "Launching MyProjectName". java.lang.NullPointerException*

Now even if I change back to 2.2, I cannot make my old classes run. Again, Eclipse-hell has broken out. Its huge mess fails to find its own files. What can be done to help this? Other that starting all over again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change your build target for an application, you need to  follow these steps

1. Project -> Right Click and Select properties
2. Select Android option on left side pane
3. In the Project Build Target on right side pane, select the target you wish

That is it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd do Project > Clean in Eclipse to see if it helps.